# 5 subfigures for two rows, 3 and 2, and the second row is not centered

Tags: graphics, subcaption

```
\begin{figure}[h] % figure will span both columns in article
\centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth} % common settings of images widths
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{./Figures/a.png}
    \caption{cap1}
    \label{1}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{./Figures/s.png}
    \caption{cap2}
    \label{2}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{./Figures/d.png}
    \caption{cap3}
    \label{3}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{./Figures/f.png}
    \caption{cap4}
    \label{4}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{./Figures/g.png}
    \caption{cap5}
    \label{5}
\end{subfigure}%
    \caption{figure}
    \label{total}
\end{figure}
```

I want captions and labels for each subfigure, the only flaw of this code is the 2 subfigures in the second row are not centered, they fill the whole row by making a big space
Thank you!

Comment: Leave out the `\hfill` between them.

Comment: Off-topic: Are you sure the "figure will span both columns in article" comment is accurate and/or appropriate? Is your document really in two-column mode? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Remove *both* `\centering` instructions. The first one is not doing anything useful, and the second runs counter to what you say you want to achieve in the title of your posting, *viz.*, "the second row is not centered".
- Replace the *last* `\hfill` instruction with `\hspace{0.05\textwidth}%`; the `%` symbol is important. Why `0.05\textwidth`? In row 1, the three graphs take up `0.9\textwidth`; this leaves `0.1\textwidth` for the two inter-graph whitespace gaps. Half of `0.1\textwidth` is `0.05\textwidth`.
- Replace the second-to-last `\hfill` instruction with a blank line and a `\bigskip` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in final document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] % figure will span both columns in article % really?

%%\centering % <-- no need to use \centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth} % common settings of images widths

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{./Figures/a.png}
    \caption{cap1}
    \label{1}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{./Figures/s.png}
    \caption{cap2}
    \label{2}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{./Figures/d.png}
    \caption{cap3}
    \label{3}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip % <-- leave a blank line (to cause a line break) and '\bigskip'
%% \centering  % <-- this instruction is counterproductive
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}% <-- the "%" symbol is needed
    \includegraphics{./Figures/f.png}
    \caption{cap4}
    \label{4}
\end{subfigure}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}% <-- instead of '\hfill'
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{./Figures/g.png}
    \caption{cap5}
    \label{5}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{A figure with five subfigures}
\label{fig:total}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```